# I first wrote jQuery and it doesn't work :((

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, error-handling

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUBIo.png)

I thought I was wrong with jQuery connection but I tested with function(){console.log}
and it worked. but after function addNumber()~ is not work at all...

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 12 to 23 all use class selectors *with* a period, after that it seems like you've forgotten the period in all instances of `'section_' + a` which should be `'.section_' + a`. This doesn't answer your question but there's also the output element which not many people know about: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output

I have to add, I never comment or ask questions but in this case I do recommend you try to ask your questions more clearly and do some research before asking because your questions amounts to: I don't know what I'm doing wrong, please find my errors

Comment: thanks for your appreciate. I never learned it so I quite don't know how to ask.
anyway, your answer is very thankful to me thanks! :))

Answer (score 0):

You probably missed a period in the jquery selector for the section classes that you wrote.

```
$('.section_three button').click(function () {
  your_action()
})
```

You can go ahead and read up the documentation on how to use jquery selectors properly
https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/